# How to make a brightly glowing Icoshadron in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I wanted to create a brightly glowing Icoshadron Geometry in Three.js.

I could not get any code to create such a glow. So i appended the Icoshadron Geometry (using MeshStandardMaterial with opacity .5) into a Group & added 27 lights on it using a for loop.
Below is my code-

```js
import { AdditiveBlending, FrontSide, MeshStandardMaterial } from "three";
import { ShaderMaterial } from "three";
import { Group } from "three";
import { AmbientLight } from "three";
import { Color } from "three";
import { PointLight } from "three";
import { IcosahedronGeometry } from "three";
import { Mesh, PerspectiveCamera, Scene, WebGLRenderer } from "three";

const container = document.body;

const scene = new Scene();

const fov = 35;
const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
const near = 0.1;
const far = 10000;
const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);

const renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

const tp = performance.now();

const stoneConfigs = {
  red: {
    geometry: new IcosahedronGeometry(10, 0),
    material: new MeshStandardMaterial({
      color: new Color("red"),
      opacity: 0.5,
    }),
    position: [-24, 0, 0],
    color1: new Color("red"),
    update: function () {
      // this.position.z -= 0.1;

      this.rotation.y = (performance.now() - tp) * 0.0001;
    },
  },
  blue: {
    geometry: new IcosahedronGeometry(10, 0),
    material: new MeshStandardMaterial({
      color: 0x0000ff,
      opacity: 0.5,
    }),
    position: [24, 0, 0],
    color1: 0x0000ff,
    update: function () {
      // this.position.z -= 0.1;

      this.rotation.y = (performance.now() - tp) * 0.0001;
    },
  },
  yellow: {
    geometry: new IcosahedronGeometry(10, 0),
    material: new MeshStandardMaterial({
      color: 0xffff00,
      opacity: 0.5,
    }),
    position: [0, 0, 0],
    color1: 0xffdd00,
    update: function () {
      // this.position.z -= 0.1;

      this.rotation.y = (performance.now() - tp) * 0.1;
    },
  },
};

let stones = [];

appendStones();

function appendStones() {
  for (let stoneName in stoneConfigs) {
    const stoneConfig = stoneConfigs[stoneName];

    const stoneGroup = new Group();

    const stone = new Mesh(stoneConfig.geometry, stoneConfig.material);
    stoneGroup.add(stone);

    for (let xPos = -1; xPos < 2; xPos++) {
      for (let yPos = -1; yPos < 2; yPos++) {
        for (let zPos = -1; zPos < 2; zPos++) {
          const light = new PointLight(stoneConfig.color1, 6, 10);
          light.position.set(xPos * -10, yPos * -10, zPos * -10);
          stoneGroup.add(light);
        }
      }
    }

    stoneGroup.position.set(...stoneConfig.position);

    stones.push({ stoneConfig, stone: stoneGroup });
    scene.add(stoneGroup);
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  stones.forEach(({ stoneConfig, stone }) => {
    stoneConfig.update.bind(stone)();
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
});

addEventListener("resize", () => {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

container.append(renderer.domElement);
```

It gave me a nice result but it is insanely slow. I want to rotate the Icoshadron so i am rotating the Group but it is animating at <1fps. I am sure that the lights must be removed but what should i do instead to get the glow. (somewhat like infinity stones but even brighter & enlarged).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a bloom effect like in the following official example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom

The idea is to use post processing via `EffectComposer`. The pass chain (effect stack) should contain an instance of `RenderPass`, `UnrealBloomPass` and `OutputPass`.

- `RenderPass` renders (or saves) the scene into a render target.
- `UnrealBloomPass` applies the bloom/glow effect.
- `OutputPass` takes care of tone mapping and color space conversion.

This approach will perform better than using an huge number of lights (which will not produce a real glow effect anyway).